# Draw a workflow connection line on the canvas through two coordinate points

Tags: typescript

I want to realize a connection line similar to the one shown in the figure below, which will automatically generate a combined route of horizontal and vertical lines based on the given two coordinate points p1 and p2, and automatically avoid rectangles.

[ideal effect](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m4ZAM.png)

I try to judge the feasibility and distance between each step of up, down, left, and right to the p2 coordinates, and get a set of coordinate points, but the result is not what I want, as shown in the figure below.

```
  private GetNext(p1: Position, p2: Position) {
    let offset = [1, 1, -1, -1];
    let distance = Infinity;
    let result = { x: 0, y: 0 };
    for (let i = 0; i < offset.length; i++) {
      let o = offset[i];
      let p = i % 2 ? "y" : "x";
      let pos = { ...p1 };
      pos[p] += o;

      let dist = this.GetDistance(pos, p2);
      if (dist < distance && !this.IsRectBlocked(pos, p2)) {
        distance = dist;
        result = pos;
      }
    }
    return result;
  }

  private IsRectBlocked(startCoord: Position, endCoord: Position) {
    for (let i = 0; i < render.stage.Children.length; i++) {
      let n = render.stage.Children[i];
      if (n instanceof Rect) {
        let w = n.Width / 2,
          h = n.Height / 2;

        let { x: nx, y: ny } = n.GetStagePosition();

        let minX = nx - w;
        let maxX = nx + w;
        let minY = ny - h;
        let maxY = ny + h;

        if (startCoord.x > minX && startCoord.x < maxX && startCoord.y > minY && startCoord.y < maxY) {
          return true;
        }
      }
    }
    return false;
  }
```

[realistic effect](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nedNi.png)

This line has too many turns and I need a better train of thought